# PDO and MySql Output one row only once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When selecting and displaying records using `php's` `PDO` and `MySql`, how can I print one row once and loop through the rest? In the code below, I need to print `$row['parentName']` only once, and loop through all the other row. What is an efficient way to do it? The way I'm doing it does not work and I get `Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\web\apache\htdocs\index.php on line 227`.

I don't mind taking a whole new approach, since this isn't implemented yet.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($thisArray);
    $rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($rows >= 1) {
            echo '<div>'.$row['parentName'].'</div>'; //Echo only once.
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<div>'.$row['childName'].'</div>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'We could not find anything to display.';
        }
```

**EDIT**
I'm stuck at the `fetch` part.

Comment: You have `$rows`->`$rows = $stmt->rowCount();` but are trying to use `$row`->`$row['parentName']`. You could move `echo '<div>'.$row['parentName'].'</div>';` inside your while loop and use a counter to only print when counter is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($thisArray);
if ($stmt->rowCount() >= 1) {
    $array = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo '<div>', $array[0]['parentName'], '</div>';
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        echo '<div>', $row['childName'], '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'We could not find anything to display.';
}
```